# Items in HListView are not clickable using HorizontalListView

Tags: android, horizontallist

What I need is a Horizontal scrollable `ListView` that serves as a horizontally scrollable menu.

I searched for a solution and came up with the [this library](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView).

I am trying to implement `it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` on `it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.HListView` object in a `DialogFragment`.

I can get the list to populate but I can't seem to be able to attach listeners to the item.
I have been trying for 2 days to figure this out, but no game. This feature is still not working. So I turn to the old WWW for salvation..

This is my DialogFragment XML **fragment_layout.xml**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#800000"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

   <it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.HListView
            android:id="@+id/hlvPlacesListScrollMenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
             />
```

this is my viewitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#800000"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibScrollMenuImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#800000"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvScrollMenuTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#f4f4f4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my main_activity_layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/llDialogFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#34f34f"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Pretty basic.

My MainActicity is :

```
package com.example.hscrollviewtest;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        LifeStatsDialogFragment menuFragment = new LifeStatsDialogFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.llDialogFragment, menuFragment).commit();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

the Dialogfrgment .java :

```
package com.example.hscrollviewtest;

import it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.AdapterView;
import it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.HListView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class LifeStatsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        OnItemClickListener {

    private HListView scroll;
    private View rootView;
    private HorizontalScrollMenuAdapter mAdapter;
    final String[] IMAGE_TITLE = new String[] { "Home", "Work", "School",
            "Sport" };
    final int[] MENU_IMAGES = new int[] { R.drawable.ic_circle_home,
            R.drawable.ic_circle_work, R.drawable.ic_circle_school,
            R.drawable.ic_circle_gym };

    public LifeStatsDialogFragment newInstance() {
        return new LifeStatsDialogFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
        mAdapter = new HorizontalScrollMenuAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.fragment_layout, R.id.tvScrollMenuTitle, IMAGE_TITLE,
                MENU_IMAGES);
        scroll = (HListView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.hlvPlacesListScrollMenu);
        scroll.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        scroll.invalidate();
        scroll.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        for (int i = 0; i < scroll.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
            Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "first item in scroll : "
                    + scroll.getChildAt(i) + "and its clickable?? "
                    + scroll.getAdapter().getItemViewType(i) + "\n");
        }

        Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                "The number of children for HlistView is: "
                        + scroll.getParent().toString());

        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

and this is the adapter(which works when I use it in the HorizontalVariableListViewDemo):

```
package com.example.hscrollviewtest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HorizontalScrollMenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private String[] mButtonText;
    private int[] mIconId;
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    //Constructor
    public HorizontalScrollMenuAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, String[] menuItemName, int[] menuItemImage) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, menuItemName);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        mButtonText = menuItemName;
        mIconId = menuItemImage;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mIconId.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.viewitem, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvScrollMenuTitle);
            holder.icon=(ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ibScrollMenuImage);
            //holder.icon.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.name.setText(mButtonText[position]);
        holder.icon.setImageResource(mIconId[position]);
        holder.icon.setTag(mIconId[position]);
        Log.d(TAG,"returned view to fragment");



        return convertView;

    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView name;
        ImageButton icon;
    }


}
```

I hope one of you can see my blindspot.
Thaks

Comment: Try setting the clicklisteners inside the adapter when you create the views.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are implementing the wrong OnItemClickListener.
Try to use

```
public class LifeStatsDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try 2 things:

1. Put the fragment in the xml layout in the first place, and avoid add in the onCreate.
2. What happens in the onItemClick? - its currently empty. Try using an independent onItemClickListener:

   ```
   list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
               int position, long id) {
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       }
   });
   ```